# Return success/failure variable with ajax from php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a really new coder and struggling with a task I'm now working on and trying out for days.

I searched Google and Stack Overflow but can't find a (for me understandable) solution to my problem:

I created a Twitter Bootstrap landing page and there a modal shows up when clicked. In this modal I have a form with a newsletter subscription:

```
 <form id="newsletter" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" id="sub">Save</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Now I want to insert the data into a mySQL DB and do some basic validation that returns errors or a success message. The script works fine without ajax, but probably needs alterations on what it returns for ajax?

```
    include("connection.php");

    if ($_POST['email']) {

        if(!empty($_POST['my_url'])) die('Have a nice day elsewhere.');
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
            $error.=" please enter your email address.";
        } else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error.=" please enter a valid email address.";
        }
        if($error) {
            $error= "There was an error in your signup,".$error;
        } else {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `email_list` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($results) { 
                $error.=" this email address is already registered.";
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `email_list` (`email`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."')";
                mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $message = "Thanks for subscribing!";
            }
        }
    }
```

After a lot of reading ajax seems to be the way to do it without the bootstrap modal closing after submit (to suppress default event).

The insertion into the DB works fine, also the validation.

But I can't manage to get the different error messages displayed (stored in the $error variable of the php file) or alternatively the $message in case of success.

This is the jquery script:

```
$("#sub").submit(function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        url: "newsletter2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {email: $("#email").val()},
        success: function(message) {
            $("#result").html(message);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            $("#result").html(error);
        }
});
```

I try to display the value of the error and message variable in the php script within the #result span.

Any help is appreciated. Please formulate it very straight forward since I'm really new to this field.

Thank you a lot in advance.

**Edit:**
Added some to the php file to create an array and store the messages within:

```
    $response = array();
    $response['success'] = $success;
    $response['error']= $errors;
    exit(json_encode($response));
```

But have still some trouble to get the ajax to work. Tried the shorthand $.post instead of $.ajax but can't them now even to get to work posting data...

```
$("#sub").submit(function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("newsletter.php", {email: $("#email").val() });
});
```

Quick time is much appreciated. I'm stuck after hours of testing and can't find the error. If I submit the form regularly it works fine, so the php/mysql part isn't the problem.

I also realized that when I click the "#sub" button, it still tries to submit the form via get (URL gets values passed). So I'm not sure if the event.preventDefault(); isn't working? jQuery is installed and working.

Comment: Show me your error messages.

Comment: Use echo mate. echo $message;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $.ajax error function gets called when there is a connection error or the requested page cannot be found

You have to print some text out with the php and the ajax success function gets this output. Then you parse this output to see how it went.

The best practice is this:

php part:

```
$response = array();
$response['success'] = $success;
$response['general_message'] = $message;
$response['errors']  = $errors;
exit(json_encode($response));
```

js/html part:

```
$.post("yourpage.php", a , function (data) {
    response = JSON.parse(data);
    if(response['success']){
        //handle success here
    }else{
        //handle errors here with response["errors"] as error messages
    }
});
```

Good luck with your project

Comment: Thanks for this input! I tried the php array with json encoding and it works fine when I submit the form normally per action="newsletter.php" and method="post" :) 

But I seem stuck with the AJAX and can't even get it to work now to Post the data to the db with even a simplified version:

    $("#sub").submit(function (){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("newsletter.php", {email: $("#email").val() });

Hope I manage to get this working soon.

Comment: Hey Juri. Lets debug it a bit. Whats this code printing out in a console?

$.post("newsletter.php", a , function (data) {console.log(data)});

You open the javascript console in chrome with ctrl+shift+J

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` your messages back to your AJAX. There is no place in you PHP code where the messages are going back to the `message` variable in your AJAX success.

```
include("connection.php");

    if ($_POST['email']) {

        if(!empty($_POST['my_url'])) die('Have a nice day elsewhere.');
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
            $error.=" please enter your email address.";
            echo $error; die;
        } else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error.=" please enter a valid email address.";
            echo $error; die;
        }
        if($error) {
            $error= "There was an error in your signup,".$error;
            echo $error; die;
        } else {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `email_list` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($results) { 
                $error.=" this email address is already registered.";
                echo $error; die;
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `email_list` (`email`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."')";
                mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $message = "Thanks for subscribing!";
                echo $message; die;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried echoing out the answers before, but since the $error gets appended I coudn't make it display all the error parts at once if there was more than one. The array solution should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I basicly just had the same case. I structured my code a little bit different but it works so...

```
$("#sub").submit(function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        url: "newsletter2.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {email: $("#email").val()},

})
   .success(function(message) {
            $("#result").html(message);
        }),
    .error(function(error) {
            $("#result").html(error);
        })
```

on server side I used C#(asp.net) and just returned a Json

```
return Json(new { Message = "Something...", Passed = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! The server side with php now works, I just have to figure out the ajax call, I have an error there and can't get it to work properly to even post data to the server.

        $("#sub").submit(function (){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("newsletter.php", {email: $("#email").val() });

Glad your solution works! :) Hope mine will too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Oukay, finally I managed to solve the problem with the great inputs here. I did the following:

PHP:

```
$response = array();
$response['success'] = $success;
$response['error'] = $error;
exit(json_encode($response));
```

JS:

```
    $("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'newsletter3.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {email: $('#email').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(response);
                if (response['success']) {
                    $("#error").hide();
                    $("#success").html(response['success']);
                    $("#success").toggleClass("alert alert-success");
                } else {
                    $("#error").html(response['error']);

                    if(!$("#error").hasClass("alert alert-danger"))
                        $("#error").toggleClass("alert alert-danger");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The functionality is now that you click on a button and a modal pops-up, then you can enter your email and the php script validates if its valid and if it's already in the db. Error and success messages get JSON encoded and then are displayed in a span that changes color according to bootstrap classes danger or success.

Thank you very much for helping me, I'm very happy with my first coding problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my ajax

```
request.done(function (response, data) {
                   $('#add--response').html(response);
});
```

and this on the PHP

```
die("Success! Whatever text you want here");
```